# splitting a line and printing it takes results in a core dumped

Tags: string, fgets, strtok

When I try to read a line from standard input and split it into words, after removing the /n character, I get a core dumped error. Could anyone explain me the reason? What is the correct way to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LINE_LEN  50
#define MAX_PARTS  50

int main ()
{
    char* token;
    char *str;
    char* arr[MAX_PARTS];
    int i,j;

    printf("Write a line: \n $:");
    fgets(str, LINE_LEN, stdin);
    str = strncpy(str, str, strlen(str)-1);

    fflush(stdin);

    i=0;
    token = strtok(str, " ");
    while( token != NULL ) 
    {
        arr[i] = token;
        printf("%s",arr[i]);
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the NULL pointer on your last pass through the while() loop. You probably need to reverse the printf() and strtok() calls like this:

```
while( token != NULL ) 
{
    arr[i] = token;
    printf("%s",arr[i]);         # Must come first to avoid printing a NULL on final loop
    i++;
    token = strtok(NULL," ");
}
```

Comment: Stella - this is working fine for me. I am using Ubuntu Linux with gcc 4.6.3. You are most likely using a different input string than I am - can you post a particular input that is causing a crash? Do you know what line it is crashing on?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised I posted the wrong code snippet! Please let me edit my question. Anyway you are right about the while loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**You are reading into unallocated memory.**

```
char *str;
```

This declares a pointer `str`, which is pointing nowhere. (In fact, it points to a random location, but "nowhere" stops the guys who try to second-guess undefined behaviour.)

```
fgets(str, LINE_LEN, stdin);
```

This writes to the location `str` is pointing at, which is nowhere (see above). This is undefined behaviour. If your program happens to survive this (instead of SEGFAULTing right there), you cannot rely on it behaving in any sane manner from this point on.

While we're at it:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Note that the C standard does not define the behaviour of `fflush()` when called on input streams, i.e. while this is well-defined under Linux (which *does* define this behaviour), this is a non-standard, non-portable construct that could well crash on other platforms.